# LINQ Xelement Returns null when child node exist

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have a XML file like this and I want to read the ID, shortname, Name node value.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<AccountingUnitList xmlns="http://www.google.com">
<AccountingUnit>
<ID>17406</ID> 
<ShortName>test</ShortName> 
<Name>test</Name> 
</AccountingUnit>
<AccountingUnit>
<ID>18006</ID> 
<ShortName>ANOTHERtest</ShortName> 
<Name>Anothertest</Name> 
</AccountingUnit>
<AccountingUnit>
<ID>18046</ID> 
<ShortName>RKU</ShortName>
<Name>hospital</Name> 
</AccountingUnit>
<AccountingUnit>
<ID>18047</ID> 
<ShortName>MNU</ShortName> 
<Name>MNU</Name> 
</AccountingUnit>
</AccountingUnitList>
```

what is the best way to read the Node element recursively?

This is how I am trying to read the Node value:

```
var accountingunit = ( 
                from e in XDocument.Parse(textresult).Root.Elements("AccountingUnit")
                select new node
                {
                     idvalue = (string)e.Element("ID"),
                     shortname =(string)e.Element("ShortName"),
                     name = (string)e.Element("Name"),

                });

            foreach(var unit in accountingunit)
            {
               Console.WriteLine("ID"+ unit.idvalue + unit.name + unit.shortname);
            }
```

Here is the node consructor:

```
public class node
{
    public string idvalue { get; set; }
    public string shortname { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Show what you tried please.

Comment: With some googling, you find the answers.  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504057/xdocument-get-xml-element-by-the-value-of-its-name-attribute

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8460464/finding-element-in-xdocument

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566167/query-an-xdocument-for-elements-by-name-at-any-depth

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/vstudio/en-US/3d457c3b-292c-49e1-9fd4-9b6a950f9010/how-to-get-tag-name-of-xml-by-using-xdocument

Comment: Add the word recursive and you get more!

http://www.codearsenal.net/2012/12/csharp-reading-xml-document-recursively.html

http://forums.asp.net/t/1535653.aspx?Traversing+XML+file+using+recursion

http://ehikioya.com/get-xml-document-nodes-recursively/

Answer (score 17):

You have an xml namespace in your document.All the child elements of `AccountingUnitList` inherits the namespace so you need to specify it via element name:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.google.com";

var accountingunit = ( 
            from e in XDocument.Parse(textresult).Elements(ns + "AccountingUnit")
            select new node
            {
                 idvalue = (string)e.Element(ns + "ID"),
                 shortname =(string)e.Element(ns + "ShortName"),
                 name = (string)e.Element(ns + "Name"),

            });
```

Comment: @user1514428 try removing the `.Root`. Since you are using `XElement.Parse` root is already `AccountingUnitList`

Comment: @user1514428 It seems I miss the namespace here: `.Elements(ns + "AccountingUnit")` try again

Comment: Thank you very much it worked but i have one problem. Actually the xml is result of a webservice request of all Accountingunit but if i request for one particular accountingunit id the the XML is like this
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
 <AccountingUnit xmlns="http://www.google.com">
  <ID>10000</ID> 
  <ShortName>TEST KH 01</ShortName> 
  <Name>ORBIS TEST-Krankenhaus 01</Name> 
  <FinancialAccountSystem>1</FinancialAccountSystem> 
  </AccountingUnit>
how can do it ?.

Comment: if the xml is like this  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> <AccountingUnit xmlns="google.com">; <ID>10000</ID> <ShortName>TEST KH 01</ShortName> <Name>ORBIS TEST-Krankenhaus 01</Name> <FinancialAccountSystem>1</FinancialAccountSystem> </AccountingUnit>
what should i use in .Elements(ns + ? ) . thank you.

Comment: @user1514428 It seems your problem requires a new question, please only use comments to ask for further details. Also, if this question helped you, please green mark it.