# Get Value by Name of the same Element in XML using C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm having a following XML, in that I'm having two Nodes namely "param" but the Names are different. I need to get the value by Name from the node param. Kindly look at the code

```
void Main()
{
    string _commentXml = string.Format("<root>{0}{1}</root>"
                             , "<param name=\"Super\">Parameter One</param>"
                             , "<param name=\"Supreme\">Parameter Two</param>");

    XmlDocument _comment = new XmlDocument();
    _comment.LoadXml(_commentXml);


    XElement element = XElement.Load(_comment.DocumentElement.CreateNavigator().ReadSubtree());
    TryGetElementValue(element, "param").Dump();
}

public string TryGetElementValue(XElement parentEl, string elementName, string defaultValue = null)
{
    var foundEl = parentEl.Element(elementName);

    if (foundEl != null)
    {
        var xyz = foundEl.Elements("param");

        if (xyz != null)
        {
            return xyz.First(x => x.Attribute("name").Value == "Super").Value;
        }
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```

I can't able to get the value of `param` with `name=Super`

I refereed one of the stack-overflow question which is opt for this requirement but I can't.

Referred: [XDocument get XML element by the value of its name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504057/xdocument-get-xml-element-by-the-value-of-its-name-attribute)

Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why all this mess?

`XDocument` has a `Descendants` method and with linq it's easy:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(_commentXml);
var xel = xdoc.Descendants("param")
              .Where(xElement => xElement.Attribute("name")?.Value == "Super");
```

Comment: @DaveBecker simple condition: `xElement.Attribute("name") != null && xElement.Attribute("name").Value == "Super"`

Answer (score 0):

You can also user XPath.

```
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("/path/to/element/I/want");
```

In your case it would be something like this:

```
var element = doc.XPathSelectElement("/root/param[@name="Super"]");
```

Check here for more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11224645/1582065